# PHP array grouping/conditionals is it possible?

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a bit of an issue that I dug myself into.  I have a list of items that have a field of what type of boxes they will fit in.

For example:

```
item    | boxtype   | Quantity
-------------------------------
item1   | A-10,C-20 | 3
item2   | C-10,D-20 | 2
```

The letter in the boxtype-column is the box type, the number that follows is how many of the item can fit in it.

What I am trying to figure out how to use the least amount of boxes.  I originally just divided the quantity by the letter number, if it was under 1 I used that box.

But on cases like the above, where i would use Box A for item1, on item2 I would have to use C.  It would be better to use box C for both items since all of both items would fit.

Of course this is just a simplied version of the issue, if needed I could elaborate with more defined example.  I was just wondering could I do all the sorting with arrays?

Thanks for any point in the right direction

EDIT - adding this array, from this array, is there an easy way test for conditions of the letters to determine which box type should be used?

```
    Array
    (
        [AC] => Array
            (
                [A] => 0.75
                [C] => 0.15
            )

        [CD] => Array
            (
                [C] => 0.2
                [D] => 0.1
            )
    )
```

Comment: This is really not at all clear.

Comment: So you basically need an algorithm that will pick the perfect box? If there are only a few items pick the smallest box, if there are a lot, pick the most suitable box (just big enough for all items). Am i correct?

Comment: Sort of, the idea is to go with the smallest box and fewest boxes.  The problem I am having is when there are many items.  Just one is simple, and 2 with unrelated box types are simple, but when multiples of items that have 1 similar box type and 1 different and trying to figure out what boxes is getting complicated.

Comment: So not only you have many items, you also mix those items in a box? Let's say 2 items1, 1 item2 and 3 items3, which box would be just big enough for all of those together. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, an item can fit into multiple boxes, and more than 1 different item can be in the same box.  What I have is the amount of an item that fits a particular box, but I do not have the size of said item or size of the box.  If I had those things then I could just figure out cubic inches to get a good guess.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a 1D/linear [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). I don't see what it has to do with a particular language (PHP) or feature (arrays). For those, please come up with a more concrete example (e.g.: How do I sort this array in PHP? `array(blah => blah)`). For the former, do not specify a language at all, focus on the algorithm.

Comment: I saw that when search and am completely dumbfounded on how to even start to make that work :)

Comment: I could post a full array of items, box types, number of items that fit each box and quantity, but the array could be built in so many different ways I wasn't sure if I should post one.

Comment: @Sam Simpson: So am I (dumbfounded). But that's normal for one's first exposure to a new topic. Focus on algorithms. Use a language to realize those algorithms, and don't get stuck on petty limitations or features.